# Тег <picture> и загрузка изображений клиенту

Tags: html

Знаю, что  `img`, то бишь изображения начинают подгружаться клиенту еще до загрузки всего dom. А как тег `<picture>` на это влияет? 
Допустим, хочу сделать в адаптивной версии сайта разные версии логотипов.
Получается, они все загрузятся, а потом будет выбран подходящий?
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы клиенту приходили не все изображения?

Comment: Ну это же легко проверить в браузерах в средствах разработки. Поменяйте размер браузера, перезагрузите страницу и посмотрите какой файл загрузился.

Comment: Точно, спасибо, очень выручили меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `srcset` для `<img>`. При использовании `srcset` браузер сам выбирает, какое изображение подойдёт больше из списка указанных.

Comment: Да, но вопрос-то был в том, загружает ли он все изображения сразу, а потом выбирает или сначала выбирает нужный, а потом загружает его?

Comment: Загружается только необходимое изображение.